# Law of reflection in vector form: how is $\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 - 2(\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s}) \vec{s}$ derived?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

I am told that the **law of reflection** can be stated in the following two parts:

1. The angle of reflection is equal to the angle of incidence.
2. The incident ray, the normal to the reflecting surface at the point of incidence, and the reflected ray lie in a plane.

I am then told that both parts of the law can be put into vector form as

$$\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 - 2(\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s}) \vec{s},$$

where $\vec{n}_1$, $\vec{n}_2$, and $\vec{s}$ are the unit vectors of the incident ray, the reflected ray, and the normal to the surface, respectively.

I don't understand exactly how $\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 - 2(\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s}) \vec{s}$ was derived. How is this derived from the two parts of the law of reflection?

Comment: Draw a vector diagram. For simplicity, start with $\vec s$ as $\hat z$. Define $\theta_i$ and $\theta_r$ appropriately. What component of the incident vector is unchanged by reflection?

Comment: @robphy But $\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 - 2(\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s}) \vec{s}$ doesn't even include the angle of incidence or the angle of reflection, so that's partly why I find this confusing. Perhaps this uses the dot product definition $\dfrac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}{\left\vert \left\vert \vec{a} \right\vert \right\vert \left\vert \left\vert \vec{b} \right\vert \right\vert} = \cos(\theta)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality between the angles can be derived as follows.  Take the dot product $\vec{n}_2 \cdot \vec{s}$:
$$
\vec{n}_2\cdot \vec{s} = \vec{n}_1\cdot \vec{s} - 2(\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s}) (\vec{s} \cdot \vec{s}) = - \vec{n}_1\cdot \vec{s} = \vec{n}_1 \cdot (-\vec{s}).
$$
In other words, the dot product between $\vec{n}_2$ and $\vec{s}$ is the same as the angle between $\vec{n}_1$ and $-\vec{s}$.  That means that the cosines of the angles between each pair of vectors are the same.  But if you sketch these vectors out, you'll see that $\theta_r$ is the angle between $\vec{n}_2$ and $\vec{s}$, while $\theta_i$ is the angle between $\vec{n}_1$ and $ - \vec{s}$.  Thus, $\theta_r = \theta_i$.

For the property that all three vectors are coplanar, this is just a general statement about vectors:  if you can write a vector as the sum or the difference of two others, then all three vectors (the sum and the two original vectors) lie in a plane.  Here, we are subtracting $\vec{n}_1$ and $2(\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s}) \vec{s}$, so $\vec{n}_2$ must lie in the same plane as these.

As far as how you'd actually derive these formulas from first principles, I would encourage you to look over the Wikipedia page for [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection), which explains how to use dot products to decompose a vector into its components parallel and perpendicular to another vector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How did you get that $\vec{n}_1\cdot \vec{s} - 2(\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s}) (\vec{s} \cdot \vec{s}) = - \vec{n}_1\cdot \vec{s}$?

Comment: @ThePointer What is $\vec s\cdot \vec s$?

Comment: @robphy Oh, yes, $\vec{s}$ is a *unit* vector, so $\vec{s} \cdot \vec{s}$ is $1$. The notation confused me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have a look at the above picture, once we shifted $\hat{i}$ to be at the same point from where $\hat{r}$ originates from, we see we have to move up twice by the component of $\hat{i}$ along $\hat{n}$ i.e:

$$ \hat{r} = \hat{i} - 2 ( \hat{i} \cdot \hat{n} ) \hat{n}$$

Further illustration:
[image]

QED

---

*: On [free vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector)

Note: The role Snell's law plays in this derivation is that it tells us how to draw the picture, we can prove from a little geometry that this is indeed how the components different but why bother when we can read it off from the image?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "... we see we have to move up twice by the component of $\hat{i}$ along $\hat{n}$ ..." I don't see how it shows this.

Comment: @ThePointer check the added picture

Answer (score 0):

With two input vectors ($\hat n_1, \hat s$), you need to create one output vector:

$$ \hat n_2 = a\hat n_1 + b\hat s + c(\hat n_1 \times \hat s) + d \hat n_1 (\hat n_1\cdot \hat s) + f \hat s (\hat n_1\cdot \hat s)$$

with $a,b,c,d,f$ equal to constants.

Under a parity transformation, vectors change sign, cross products do not:

$$ -\hat n_2 = -a\hat n_1  -b\hat s + c(\hat n_1 \times \hat s) - d \hat n_1 (\hat n_1\cdot \hat s) - f \hat s (\hat n_1\cdot \hat s)$$

so $c=0$.

Under time reversal, wave vectors flip sign, plane-normals do not:

$$ -\hat n_2 = -a\hat n_1  +b\hat s  + d \hat n_1 (\hat n_1\cdot \hat s) - f \hat s (\hat n_1\cdot \hat s)$$

so $b=d=0$.

That leaves us with:

$$\hat n_2  = a \hat n_1 +f \hat s(\hat n_1 \cdot \hat s)$$

as the only acceptable form of the relationship.

At glancing incidence (i.e., $\hat n_1 \cdot \hat s=0$), there is no reflection:

$$\hat n_2  =_{|_{90^{\circ}}} a \hat n_1  = \hat n_1$$

so $a=1$.

At normal incidence, $ \hat n_2 = -\hat n_1 = \hat s$, and the relation becomes:

$$ -\hat s = \hat s + f \hat s(\hat s\cdot \hat s) = \hat s(1+f)$$

so that $f=-2$.

Putting it all together:

$$ \hat n_2 = \hat n_1 - 2 \hat s(\hat s\cdot \hat n_1) $$

which in operator form is:

$$ \hat n_2 = {\bf R} \hat n_1 $$

with the reflection operator defined as:

$$ {\bf R} = [{\bf 1} - 2(\hat s\hat s)]$$

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers by @MichaelSeifert and others  already given,

Note that
$$\vec n_1= 
\quad
\vec n_{1,||\ to\ \hat s}
\quad+\quad
\vec n_{1,\bot\ to\ \hat s}
$$
where
$\vec n_{1,||\ to\ \hat s}=(\vec n_1\cdot \hat s)\hat s$ $\qquad\quad$ (Check that $\hat s \cdot \vec n_{1,||\ to\ \hat s}=(\vec n_1\cdot \hat s)$.)
so that
$\vec n_{1,\bot\ to\ \hat s}=\vec n_1-(\vec n_1\cdot \hat s)\hat s$. $\quad$
(Check that $\hat s \cdot \vec n_{1,\bot\ to\ \hat s}=0$.)

Furthermore,
$\vec n_{1,||\ to\ \hat s}$ has magnitude $n_1\cos\theta_{between\ \vec n_1\ and\ \hat s}=n_1 \cos\theta_{incident}$,

and 
$\vec n_{1,\bot\ to\ \hat s}$ has magnitude $n_1\sin\theta_{between\ \vec n_1\ and\ \hat s}=n_1 \sin\theta_{incident}$.

In a reflection, the "normal component (perpendicular to the interface)" of the incident vector is flipped. That's the **law of reflection.**

*Note that the parallel component is unchanged by the interface,

which could be a useful observation. (Hint, Hint)*

Mathematically,
**subtracting the normal-component** (that is, $\vec n_1 - \vec n_{1,||\ to\ \hat s}$)
  gives only the component parallel to the interface (that is, $\vec n_{1,\bot \ to\ \hat s}$).

Thus, we need to **subtract twice the normal-component**
to obtain the reflected direction.
That is,
(that is, $$\vec n_2=\vec n_1 - 2\vec n_{1,||\ to\ \hat s} \quad = \quad\vec n_1 - 2(\vec n_1\cdot \hat s).$$

(It is unfortunate that the incident and reflected vectors are called
$\vec n_1$ and $\vec n_2$. Since these variable names would be more appropriate
for the indices of refraction. $\hat i$, $\hat r$ or $\hat u_i$,  $\hat u_r$ would have been better.)

The next logical step (since the Law of Reflection is now expressed vectorially)

would be to express the Law of Refraction vectorially. *(Hint, Hint).*

Answer (score 0):

This is a way we can derive the vector form of laws of reflection.

I mixed some geometry, trigonometry and vectors for the proof.

[image]

Comment: Images are not accessible to all users. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type out variables and equations.

Answer (score 0):

we are given unit vectors i, n and r. Lets consider vector t perpendicular to n and parllel to mirror/tangent.

```
cos theta  = i.n = r.n
vector i can be written in the terms of n and t as:
i = - n cos theta + t sin theta
and r as:
r = n cos theta + t sin theta = 2n cos theta -n cos theta +t sin theta
  = 2n cos theta + ( - n cos theta + t sin theta)
  = 2 n cos theta + i = 2 (i.n) n + i
```

Comment: Please use MathJax to write out mathematical formulas;  [here's a guide on how to do so.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)