# What is the justification for having $\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s} \approx \mu_1$ under the paraxial approximation, and how does it tie in with the result?

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

I am currently studying the textbook *Introduction to Optical Metrology* by R. S. Sirohi. Section **1.3 Law of Refraction** says the following:

> Refraction takes place when the light travels from one medium to the other. An isotropic and homogeneous medium is characterized by an index of refraction or refractive index $\mu$, which is the ratio of the velocity of light in vacuum to that in the medium. The law of refraction can also be stated into two parts as.
>
> 1. $\mu_1 \sin(\theta_i) = \mu_2 \sin(\theta_r)$
> 2. The incident ray, the normal to the surface separating the media at the point of incidence, and the refracted ray lie in one plane.
>
> Both the parts of the law of refraction can also be cast in a single vectorial equation as
> $$\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 - (\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s}) \vec{s} + \left( \sqrt{(\mu_2)^2 - (\mu_1)^2 + (\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s})^2} \right) \vec{s}, \tag{1.2}$$
> where $\theta_i$ and $\theta_r$ are the angles of incidence and refraction, respectively. The refractive indices of the two media are $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, and the incident ray is in the medium of refractive index $\mu_1$.
> Under paraxial approximation, the angle $\theta_i$ is small and hence $\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s} \approx \mu_1$. Therefore, the laws of refraction can be expressed as
> $$\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)\vec{s} \tag{1.3}$$

I recently [asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/650655/141502) how this was derived. The user 'JEB' [answered](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/650685/141502) with a correct step-by-step derivation, resulting in

$$\hat n_r = \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}[\hat n_i-(\hat n_i\cdot \hat s)\hat s] + \sqrt{1- \left\Vert\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}[\hat n_i-(\hat n_i\cdot \hat s)\hat s] \right\Vert^2}\hat s$$

But, continuing with the textbook explanation, what is the justification for having $\vec{n}_1 \cdot \vec{s} \approx \mu_1$ under the paraxial approximation, and how does it tie in with JEB's result? The textbook author says that this paraxial approximation allows the law of refraction to be expressed as $\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)\vec{s}$, so I'm not how we get here.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $\overrightarrow{n}_1$ and $\overrightarrow{s}$ are both unit vectors, so their dot product equals cos $\mathrm{\theta}$. Cos $\theta$ is always smaller than 1 while $\mu_1$ is always bigger than 1. It seems contradictory.

Comment: @KamKahSen JEB said in his answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/650685/141502 that he has all $\hat n_{\alpha}$ as unit vectors, but the non-hat vectors $\vec{n}$ are not. It isn't clear what convention the textbook author is using here, so I'm guessing that's where the confusion comes from.